# If $R$ is a partial order and $a,b$ are incomparable, then the transitive closure of $R\cup\{(a,b)\}$ is antisymmetric

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, order-theory

Claim: Let $T_0$ be the transitive closure of $R\cup\{(a,b)\}$. Then $T_0$ is antisymmetric.
*Proof.*
Note that since $R$ is transitive, $x T_0 y$ means that $x R a, b R y$ or $x R y$.
Suppose $x T_0 y\land y T_0 x$.
*Case 1*:$x R a, b R y\land y R x$

*Case 2*:$x R a, b R y\land yRa,bRx$

*Case 3*: $xRy\land yRa,bRx$
Not possible since by transivity $bRa$.

*Case 4*: $xRy\land yRx$
Then $x=y$.

Is the proof valid? Should I prove $xT_0y\to(xRa,bRy)\lor xRy$?
Also a logic question: When I assume $xT_0y$ and $yT_0x$, I need to show that $x=y$ in all 4 cases. We have as a premise that $a,b$ are incomparable, so the first 3 cases are basically irrelevant, right? Since they get a contradiction against the premises, it's not a problem, but if they got a contradiction against antisymmetry, then it'd be a problem.